# adding a string to a list is creating a list of characters

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a script that searches for emails inside a list. The problem is when adding the email found to the email list it returns the email string but it is chopped like in .split()

```
my_list = ['jose', 'ana', 'ana@gmail.com']
email_list = []

for i in my_list:
    if '@gmail.com' in i:
        print(i)
        email_list += i

print(email_list)
```

the first print() statement returns what I expected 'ana@gmail.com', but when I print the email_list I get it all chopped, output:

```
ana@gmail.com
['a', 'n', 'a', '@', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm']
```

Comment: `email_list += [i]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add to a list like that. You'll want to use `email_list.append(i)`

Python does this because you can do mathematical operations on list and do fun things, e.g.

```
l = []
l = 5 * [2]
l
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I really don't understand why, I know you can chop a string using a for loop, but that's not what I did and the print function returned the right result so I'm really confused why python did that